# Django query fails with _id that is not used or created or referenced to

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have used the queryset before though this is my first attempt to JOIN tables but it's not working so far.
I am using django 3.2 and python 3.8.1

my models.py

```
class Mainjoinbook(models.Model):
    fullsitename = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField()
    entrytypeid = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tickettype = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    ticket = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mainlogbook'

class Sitelocation(models.Model):
    site_name = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    latitude = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sites = models.ForeignKey(Mainjoinbook, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tblsiteaccess'
```

I am trying to get all values from both tables joined in my views.py

```
qrylocations = Sitelocation.objects.select_related('sites').filter(sites__status='OPEN')
```

this results in this error as that column is created by django but doesn't belong to the table. I still can't workout how to resolve this as I have tried many options but always get in some kind of error and I hope someone can help me to see what I'm doing wrong in joining the tables on the primary keys defined

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column tblsiteaccess.sites_id does not exist
```

the SQL output shown is as below.

output from qrylocations.query

```
SELECT "tblsiteaccess"."site_name", "tblsiteaccess"."latitude", "tblsiteaccess"."longitude", "tblsiteaccess"."sites_id", "mainlogbook"."fullsitename", "mainlogbook"."log_id", "mainlogbook"."creationdate", "mainlogbook"."entrytypeid", "mainlogbook"."title", "mainlogbook"."tickettype", "mainlogbook"."ticket", "mainlogbook"."status" FROM "tblsiteaccess" INNER JOIN "mainlogbook" ON ("tblsiteaccess"."sites_id" = "mainlogbook"."fullsitename") WHERE "mainlogbook"."status" = OPEN
```

Comment: Did you make this table by using `inspectdb`? Do you know the actual column name of the foreign key `sites` in the table `tblsiteaccess`?

Comment: If you create a `ForeignKey`, then Django normally will add `_id` to the name for the corresponidng column in the database.

Comment: yes @AbdulAzizBarkat, the tables in the models come from `inspectdb`. `sites` column was only for foreign key, it's not present in the table. I expect to get `JOIN ON "tblsiteaccess"."site_name" = "mainlogbook"."fullsitename"`, which obviously I am doing it wrong

Comment: @engstuff that's not a great primary key what happens when one wants to change the name of a `Mainjoinbook` object? It's not effiecient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ForeignKey` naturally needs a column in the database table. Since `site_name` itself is the primary key you should use that as a `ForeignKey` here, infact instead of a `ForeignKey` this needs to be a [`OneToOneField` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) since it is also a primary key and needs to be unique:

```py
class Sitelocation(models.Model):
    site_name = models.OneToOneField(
        Mainjoinbook,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        db_column='site_name'
    )
    latitude = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tblsiteaccess'
```

Comment: thanks @Abdul Aziz Barkat , as I said I knew was doing something wrong and reading all the docs was confusing me even more. that helped me to understand much better how the foreignkey works

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. `db_column` option is helpful.
In this case...

```
class Sitelocation(models.Model):
    site_name = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    latitude = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    sites = models.ForeignKey(Mainjoinbook, 
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        db_column="sites"
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tblsiteaccess'
```